# Can't boot vhdx in hyper-v after creation with disk2vdh

Tags: virtual-machine, vhd, disk2vhd

I am trying to take a machine from a physical machine to a virtual. I created a vhdx of the hard drive with the systinternals disk2vhd tool.

The vhdx is on a usb hard drive. I attached the drive to another machine and created a new virtual machine in Hyper-V that used the vhdx. When I start the new virtual machine, it give an error message indicating that there is a boot failure do to the fact that no bootable media was found.

Is there a way to diagnose this problem? I can verify that the virtual machine is using my vhdx file which was created from a physical hard drive that is certainly bootable.

Comment: Are you really sure the boot partition resides on the disk you imaged?

Comment: The only 2 disks I could select are the drive in my laptop and my external drive. I am writing the vhd to the external drive. I am imaging the internal hard drive, so I believe I am imaging the drive with the boot partition on it.

Comment: Is your laptop a (relatively) recent device? Windows might boot using UEFI. In that case, you need to resture the UEFI NVRAM boot entries in your (Gen2) VM, for example using `bcdboot`. Please provide a list of partitions (and their filesystems/IDs) currently present in your VHDX.

Comment: The VHDX has 3 partitions. One is a 300 MB Recovery Partition. One is a 99 MD EFI System Partition. One is a large NTFS partition. I don't know how do get their IDs. It does seem that I am booting with UEFI. Does bcdboot work with HyperV?